# I need to use the MySQL column in a REGEXP on the right hand side

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_messenger_keyword AS a
WHERE (a.shortCode = ? OR a.shortCode = '-1') AND ? REGEXP a.rule
```

I now get

```
[Err] 3685 - Illegal argument to a regular expression.
```

This used to work in previous versions of MySQL and I am wondering if there is anyway around this.

The field rule contains the regular expressions that need to be compared against.

I upgraded my local development box to v8.0.16 and it stopped this part of the application from working. I'd like to future proof the applcation for when we upgrade our production database.

Comment: try `AND a.rule REGEXP ?`

Comment: Try posting the whole query

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ... As in [MySQL 8.0.16](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a28ffd68ffd4fe1c44bea3da8d4b533) is still seams `REGEXP` allowes a expression..  Pretty use `Illegal argument to a regular expression.` is caused by a invalid chars in the `a.rule` column

Comment: @James that is the whole query. and using it on the LHS wouldnt work because the regular expression is stored in the database.

Comment: @RaymondNijland it seems you are correct the problem is bad regex in the column. I can perform it with the expression on the LHS and column on the RHS if I limit to a row I know has valid regex. Thanks